# Editing an answer when wanting to award a bounty to it

Tags: discussion, bounty, editing-help

I am offering a bounty on an old question (not mine), and there are some new answers to it. One of the answers is closest to what I am looking for in terms of being worth the bounty award, but there are a few syntax errors in his code example (it doesn't work out of the box).

I spent a few minutes and figured out how to correct his sample code to a working state, but now I am unsure what I should do:

1. Edit the person's answer so that the syntax is correct. Now that it works, award the bounty.
2. Comment on the person's answer, saying that the syntax is incorrect. Have him figure out himself how to fix it so it works. Once it works, award the bounty.
3. Comment on the person's answer, giving him the syntax so that it works. Wait for him to edit his answer to include the correct syntax (so that it shows that he edited the answer, and not me). Once it works, award the bounty.

I feel a bit dirty about editing an answer to be a state that I like, and then awarding the bounty to it. On the other hand, for options 2 and 3, it feels like I would be "playing teacher" and knowing the right answer but choosing not to say it, so the other person figures it out on his own (wasting his time?).

Comment: In general, don't touch code, unless you have edit privileges (> 2k reputation). Suggested edits that *fix* code have a higher chance of being rejected. Leave a comment.

Comment: For clarification, you can edit under 2k rep, but then it has to be peer-reviewed. 2k rep just means your edits are applied immediately.

But, to the issue at hand, no editing rules out option 1. So then that leaves options 2 and 3. Which one of those is preferred?

Comment: 2. if you're in a hurry, 3. if you want be nice and inclusive.

Comment: I agree that an up vote is the proper response, then if you'd like to help others not waste their time, answer your own question, mark it as the answer (and then nobody will get the reward?) You don't get your own bounty on it, but nobody actually figured out the answer anyway, they just helped.

Comment: Any time you see small syntax errors in code, just edit it to fix immediately.  Same as when you see spelling errors in the text.

Comment: @rene *"In general, don't touch code, unless you have edit privileges"* - I see no logic behind this, and it is inconsistent with the [FAQ entry on editing code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1709587) which mentions pre-2k editors changing code without discouraging it.  I really wish people would stop repeating these warnings against editng code. There's no profound difference between code edits and prose edits (either, if bad, can wreck a post), nor any special reason for pre-2k editors in particular to refrain from code edits. (Why would there be? You provide no rationale.)

Comment: @MarkAmery I think the suggestion is due to you having a chance of being rejected because some members who monitor the review queue with reject any code edits that are not formatting.

Comment: @MarkAmery: The problem with touching code isn't that touching code is bad; the problem is that people will reject your edit without trying to judge whether it's an improvement.

Comment: @Clint That sounds more like a problem with how reviews are done rather than how edits are done. I think these types of reviewers assume that if people don't have 2k rep yet, then they have 0 coding expertise, despite there being no correlation between these two. This discussion might merit its own question (or chatroom), but maybe what the editor could do to help the reviewer is write in the Summary of Changes box why he/she made the code changes. Assuming that the reviewer can see this Summary (I've not done reviewing yet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest an option you haven't considered.

Ignore your feeling of dirtiness, award the bounty.. THEN approach edits as normal

If a broken syntax, typo ridden answer solved your issue, award the bounty. The purpose of a bounty is to inspire people to answer your question and it did that; you got a usable answer, give bounty, case closed.  then follow the normal edit processes to make the answer better for the community

I think all 3 options are "playing teacher" your withholding the bounty until it meets a standard other than solving your problem... think about it the affect this has on the submitter of the answer....

"Thanks heaps for solving my problem but I'll withhold the bounty until it meets my correctness standards"

OR

"Thanks heaps for solving my problem here is your well deserved bounty. There where a few small syntax issues, that I fixed so others don't stumble on them"

Comment: "typo ridden answer": Hi! I have a few for you: "your withholding" s.b. ": you are withholding", "affect" s.b. "effect", "There where" s.b. "There were".  Don't worry I upvoted before commenting.

Comment: @NH -  :)  yep I like that  my answer demonstrated  its own message!

Comment: But too bad there's no bounty here.

Answer (score 7):

Let's ignore the bounty for a second, If the answer isn't working for you, you should comment on the answer and write your problem (and fix if you have).

This is important because you may also be wrong, and your fix may change the answer intent.

Notice you can also [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you.

> Vote up answers that are helpful and well-researched

Notice also that half bounty can be awarded [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) if answer have score of at least 2:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen.

Comment: Good point. I cannot read the answerer's mind (or the intent), so it is best to allow the person to decide whether the suggested changes are applicable.

Comment: Nah, we're here just talking about **syntax errors** - perhaps an omitted semicolon, etc.  Just click edit and fix.